# Is there a way to see a pull-request review status in magit?

Tags: magit

I see I can view the github pull requests assigned to me with `forge-list-requested-reviews`. Is there a way to see the status of each review? For example I've approved some of the pull requests that are in that list, and requested changes on others, but I can't tell which without going to the GitHub web interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, but [probably soonish](https://github.com/magit/forge/pull/266).